When choice one section go to content current section in elementor widget development
I have developed a widget for Elementor.
My widget have two section.
$this->start_controls_section(
'section1',
[
'label' => 'Section 1',
'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
]
);
//The Content 1
$this->end_controls_section();
$this->start_controls_section(
'section2',
[
'label' => 'Section 2',
'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
]
);
//The Content 2
$this->end_controls_section();

I want when click section2 in elementor go to content 2.
how do I do?
when click section2 don't go content 2 and  stay in content 2.
